# Numbering subsequences in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a *readings* DataFrame that consists of two columns, `experiment` and `value`.  `experiment` keys into an *experiments* DataFrame; there are 500 rows in a row with the same `experiment` and different `value` representing 500 readings on the same experiment where the order in the DF is the order the data was taken.  Then 500 for the next experiment, etc.

I want to look for time-based trends in the experiments, so I assume that I want to label each point `pos` in 0-499 and then `groupby('pos')`.  How do I create that `pos` column, an incrementing value that resets to 0 every time `experiment` resets?  Which is, I guess, the same as the number of rows that `experiment` has been constant for.

Comment: Your question does not explain your problem very well. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples and understand how to write a good pandas question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly...

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Experiment' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3], 
                       'Value' : np.random.randn(10)})
>>> df

   Experiment     Value
0           1 -0.924851
1           1 -0.599875
2           1  0.069982
3           2 -1.106909
4           2  0.463922
5           2  0.210568
6           2 -0.171456
7           3 -0.768618
8           3 -0.269928
9           3  0.055613
```

You will use `groupby` followed by `cumcount()` to get the desired effect:

```
>>> df['Position'] = df.groupby('Experiment').cumcount()
>>> df

   Experiment     Value  Position
0           1 -0.924851         0
1           1 -0.599875         1
2           1  0.069982         2
3           2 -1.106909         0
4           2  0.463922         1
5           2  0.210568         2
6           2 -0.171456         3
7           3 -0.768618         0
8           3 -0.269928         1
9           3  0.055613         2
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was asking for; and the solution exactly what I needed.  Thanks for your help.